# Side Navigation Menu Open Speed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wordpress website in which we have mobile side navigation menu. Its closing speed is little slow and I like it, but its opening very fast in compare of close. I want make it slow but I am not able to do it.

Let me know if anyone have idea about it.

```js
jQuery(".menu-toggle,#shadow-overlay").click(function() {
  let navbar = jQuery('#navbarCollapse');
  if (navbar.hasClass('is-showing')) {
    jQuery('.navbar-toggler').removeClass('close-menu');
    jQuery('#shadow-overlay').fadeOut(300);
    navbar.animate({
      'left': '-110vw'
    }, 500);
    navbar.removeClass('is-showing');
  } else {
    jQuery('.navbar-toggler').addClass('close-menu');
    navbar.animate({
      'left': '0'
    }, 500);
    navbar.addClass('is-showing');
    jQuery('.is-showing').fadeIn(1000);
    jQuery('#shadow-overlay').fadeIn(700);
  }
});

let distFromTop = jQuery('#horz-scroll-bar').offset().top + 50;

jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > distFromTop) {
    if (!jQuery('#horz-scroll-bar').hasClass('fixed-at-top')) {
      jQuery('#horz-scroll-bar').addClass('fixed-at-top');
    }
  }

  if (window.pageYOffset <= distFromTop) {
    jQuery('#horz-scroll-bar').removeClass('fixed-at-top');
  }
});

jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).children('a').first().on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 992) {
      jQuery(this).siblings('.sub-menu').toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava but both have same value called 500 still open is fast and close is slow!

Comment: You need to add a working example to check